# How do I properly install Virtualbox Guest Additions on PCLinuxOS?

Tags: linux, virtualbox, guest-additions, pclinuxos

I am a noob when it comes to Linux and am trying to learn how to use it. Currently I am using virtualbox version 5.2.221 and am trying to install the Virtualbox Guest Additions onto PCLinuxOS 4.16.13 by mounting the Guest Additions through virtualbox's devices tab. Unfortunatly, the Guest additions don't properly install as my screen resolution is still a tiny square and copy/paste not working between host. This is what I see when running the mounted installation:

[The Installation starting then ending immediately](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pwLpz.png)

I have been looking through countless tutorials online to find out what my issue is and cannot find a proper solution. For instance, I have tried to add the build-essentials package with the terminal and it the terminal couldn't find the package no matter how many times I used the apt-get update command.

Answer (score 0):

According to your screenshot, the Guest Additions software looks like it installed properly.  There were no errors and it said Guest Additions is starting.  Therefore I assume everything is working fine.

**The first thing I would do is  reboot the VM just to be safe.**

As for your screen resolution, the Guest Additions generally  fixes the resolution upon install in every Linux I have used.  However, maybe you might need to manually increase it PCLinux.  I have never used the PCLinux distro, but I would I would suspect its it should be easy to find the desktop settings app and try to increase it.

As for the copying and pasting, that needs to be enabled in the VM's settings in VirtualBox.  There is a checkbox to enable it.  I strongly believe it is disabled by default.

Comment: I restarted the VM, set the resolution to 1080p and the virtualbox still projects the VM as the same tiny square resolution. I also went into settings and enabled bidirectional clipboard/drag'n'drop but am unable to do that as well. It appears as though even though it tells me the guest additions are installing with no errors, that it doesn't end up installing the basic features of it.

Comment: @Timothy strange. Do you require PCLinux?  Can you use a different distro?

Comment: I can try a different distro, do you know which one is best use for VM?

Comment: Many will work. I recommend Linux Mint though

Comment: Many will work. I recommend Linux Mint though